# Displaying datepicker on custom DIV

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have bound jQueryUI datepicker to an `input` and I have a custom `div`--I'd like to bind the datepicker to that instead.

For example:

```
<input type="textbox" id="date">

<div id="datepickerDiv">
</div>
```

Script:

```
$("#date").datepicker(); // For binding to textbox.
```

I want to display the datepicker in `datepickerDiv` div.

Please help me with this...

Comment: And what problem are you having adding it to the div?

Comment: What happens when you change the selector to `#datepickerDiv`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can initialize the datepicker directly to a div.

```
$("#datepickerDiv").datepicker();
```

or

```
$("#date").on('click', function () {
    $("#datepickerDiv").datepicker(); //Initialze datepicker for div
});
```

Comment: When a datepicker is attached to a DIV element, it's displayed inline, in other words it's always visible, so how do you trigger that with a click ?

Comment: @adeneo You're right.  I will change it.  A simple thing I missed it out.  Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#datepickerDiv").datepicker(); // For binding to textbox.
```